# Attempting to destruct a HashMap Entry leads to "cannot move out of dereference of `RefMut (...) which does not implement the `Copy` trait"

Tags: rust

Consider this code:

```
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::io::{self};

use flate2::write::GzEncoder;
use flate2::Compression;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

use std::cell::RefCell;

use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut gzfiles = HashMap::new();
    for result in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let line = result.unwrap();
        let year: String = (&line[0..4]).into();
        match gzfiles.entry(year.clone()) {
            Entry::Vacant(entry) => {
                let output = File::create(year.clone()).unwrap();
                let mut encoder = GzEncoder::new(output, Compression::default());
                encoder.write(line.as_bytes());
                entry.insert(RefCell::new(encoder));
            }
            Entry::Occupied(mut entry) => {
                let mut encoder = entry.get_mut().borrow_mut();
                encoder.write(line.as_bytes());
            }
        }
    }

    for v in gzfiles.values_mut() {
        v.borrow_mut().finish().unwrap();
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=133abb3ad4c7c9af002776742c9853cc)

The goal was to create gzip files for each year and put all matching stdin lines there. For some reason I'm getting the following error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
warning: variable does not need to be mutable
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
15 |     let mut stdin = io::stdin();
   |         ----^^^^^
   |         |
   |         help: remove this `mut`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_mut)]` on by default

error[E0507]: cannot move out of dereference of `RefMut<'_, flate2::write::GzEncoder<File>>`
  --> src/main.rs:35:9
   |
35 |         v.borrow_mut().finish().unwrap();
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `flate2::write::GzEncoder<File>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
warning: `playground` (bin "playground") generated 1 warning
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error; 1 warning emitted
```

What is the compiler complaining about and how to fix it?

Comment: Why are you putting the encoder into a `RefCell`?

Comment: Next time, please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @justinas because I thought that the problem was coming from attempting to store a mutable object in the hashmap and then manipulate. The snippet fails without RefCell as well.

Comment: As @NiklasMohrin suggested, please provide a MRE. I would suggest removing `RefCell`, as it 1) did not  help; 2) would make the solution more complicated and overly specific, when it does not need to be specific to `RefCell`.

Comment: There's a rust playground link with the error they're talking about, is that not an MRE?

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier It lacks the "M" in MRE. In other words, it's not minimal, and requires the work from the responder (possibly repeated for multiple responders) to clean it up.

Answer (score 3):

The method I was looking for was [into_values](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.into_values):

> Creates a consuming iterator visiting all the values in arbitrary order. The map cannot be used after calling this. The iterator element type is V.

Here's the same snippet with RefCells removed that compiles successfully:

```
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::io::{self};

use flate2::write::GzEncoder;
use flate2::Compression;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut gzfiles = HashMap::new();
    for result in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let line = result.unwrap();
        let year: String = (&line[0..4]).into();
        match gzfiles.entry(year.clone()) {
            Entry::Vacant(entry) => {
                let output = File::create(year.clone()).unwrap();
                let mut encoder = GzEncoder::new(output, Compression::default());
                encoder.write(line.as_bytes()).unwrap();
                entry.insert(encoder);
            }
            Entry::Occupied(mut entry) => {
                let encoder = entry.get_mut();
                encoder.write(line.as_bytes()).unwrap();
            }
        }
    }

    for v in gzfiles.into_values() {
        v.finish().unwrap();
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Glad you found the answer! `GzEncoder::try_finish()` is a possible alternative solution, as it only needs a `&mut self` and not `self`. But there is a good reason why the `finish()` API is like that in the first place: you likely do not want the encoder to remain in a "zombie" (unsable) state, per the docs for `try_finish()`: "Attempts to write data to this stream may result in a panic after this function is called."

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call the `finish` method on a mutable reference to a `GzEncoder`, but this method takes the `self` by value and needs full ownership the encoder. You need to take these values out of the `HashMap`, for example by consuming the map into an iterator of its values ([`HashMap::into_values`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.into_values)). You will also have to consume the `RefCell` to get the inner value using [`RefCell::into_inner`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.into_inner).

```rust
for rc in gzfiles.into_values() {
    // `rc` is of type `RefCell<_>`, not `&mut RefCell<_>` anymore
    let encoder = rc.into_inner();
    encoder.finish().unwrap();
}
```